# How to read IDs from a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a database using txt files in which the data is stores like this: idTheme|Name|Hours.

For example: 45|Object Oriented Programming|12

I need to print the line of text with the idTheme I'm given, so I did this:

```
    print("Give me the ID")
    id_search = input("> ")

    for line in file:
        for x in line:
            if id_search != x:
                break
            else:
                print(line)
                break
```

Since the ID is always the first character in each line I thought thst would work.
Problem is, this only works when the ID is 1 character long.

I was thinking on putting the info on a list and using a split("|") to divide it but that would put all the info in the list, not only the IDs.

Any suggestions are apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use split as you said and just use index 0 to get the ID.

```
for line in file:
    id = line.split("|")[0]
    if id_search == id:
        print(line)
```

You can invert your if statement so if the id is equal to the search term it prints the line, otherwise nothing happens. You also avoid looping through the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use somethign like:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
  lines = [x.strip() for x in list(f) if x]

print("Give me the ID")
id_search = input("> ").strip()

if id_search:
  for line in lines:
    id, name, otherid = line.split("|")
    if id_search == id:
      print(line)
      break
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/aff1312a63)